# iTextSharp freezes when converting WMF to PDF file - C#

Tags: c#, itext, console-application

In this C# method, it freezes on pdfDoc.Add(img1) line. What could be causing it to freeze there and what could I do to resolve it? Thanks in Advance!

```
private bool convertwmf2pdf(string wmfFile)
        {
            try
            {
                Image img1 = ImgWMF.GetInstance(wmfFile);
                img1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);                
                img1.ScaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.Height, PageSize.A4.Width - 10);

                Document pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.Height, PageSize.A4.Width ));
                
                string pdfFile = wmfFile.ToUpper().Replace(".WMF", ".PDF");

                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite));

                pdfDoc.Open();

                pdfDoc.Add(img1);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                // delete the WMF file
                File.Delete(wmfFile);

                Console.WriteLine("PDF generated");
                
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("An error occured converting wmf file {0} to pdf. {1}", wmfFile, ex.Message));
                return false;
            }

        }
```

The code was working before and it's just suddenly acting up without any changes.

Comment: Well something had to change. Did antivirus get changed?

Comment: I figured that the cause is the image file being added (wmf file). Adding different wmf files work. But these wmf files that cause it to freeze seems to be fine files. I can open them in Paint and they display fine. I cannot find anything odd with the files.

Comment: I would contact their support